# How To Handle 'No Results Found' in a Search Feature

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to display "No Results Found" in the case where someone uses my search feature to search for something that returns no results from the database. The problem I'm running into is that "No Results Found" prints to the screen right away - then disappear when a search query is actually being evaluated - and then reappears if no results were found. In other words, it's working as it should EXCEPT that it should wait till a query is actually triggered and evaluated before printing "No Results Found" to the screen. Conceptually what's the best way to do this? On the one hand it occurs to me that I could just use a timeout. But that's not really solving the problem directly. So what would be the best way to approach this? This is the code I have for the function:

```
public get noResultsFound(): boolean
{
    if (this.query && !this._isSearching && !this.hasResults) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's my view code:

```
<div *ngIf="inputHasFocus && noResultsFound" class="no-results-found">No Results Found</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Promises sound like what you need :D
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Something along the lines of this.

```
search = (paramObj) : Promise<SomeDataClass> => {
    // Some search logic
}

requestSearch() {
    this.search(null).then((result) => {
        if (result.length === 0)
        {
            //logic for showing 0 results here
        }
        else{
            // Show result?
        }
    })
}
```

A more complete example would look a bit like this.

```
class example {
    public someBool = false;

    public search = (paramObj): Promise<Array<string>> => {
        this.someBool = !this.someBool;
        return new Promise<Array<string>>((resolver) => {
            // This just simulates something taking time.
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (this.someBool) {
                    resolver([]);
                } else {
                    resolver(["hi","there"]);
                }
            }, 1000)
        });
    }

    public requestSearch() {
        this.search(null).then((result) => {
            if (result.length === 0) {
                console.log("empty")
            }
            else {
                console.log(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end I was able to resolve this not by using some kind of debounce timeout, but by changing what the function was paying attention to - so to speak. By handling it this way the "No Results Found" never triggers before it's supposed to. This is what I ended up using:

```
public get noResultsFound(): boolean
{
    if (!Object.isNullOrUndefined(this._results) && this._results.length < 1) {
        return true;
    } 
}
```